# QGIS display diagram of data from joined (one to many) table

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a layer of parking meters.
[image]

I also have a layer of revenues of each parking meter by years. Data only, not geom. Related one to many with the parking meter layer.

I would like to be able to paint an histogram on each parking meter with historical revenues by year for each meter.

My approach would be to create a view joining both tables and making the revenue records as columns, but is there a simple way I am missing?

Comment: What about your approach is causing problems?

Comment: Developing now using crosstabs. I don't like the solution because the layer's source it's a a view and to be able to edit the parking meters I would have to add triggers and update/insert on original tables